# Regular expression to allow only the valid time offset values

Tags: regex, time

I am looking for a regular expression which allows only the time offset values.

I have used:

```
^(?:[+-](?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])$
```

The ONLY strings I need to match:

```
-12:00
+14:00
-11:00
-10:00
-09:30
-09:00
-08:00
-07:00
-06:00
-05:00
-04:00
-03:30
-03:00
-02:00
-01:00
00:00
+01:00
+04:00
+03:30
+03:00
+02:00
+04:30
+05:00
+05:30
+05:45
+06:00
+06:30
+07:00
+08:00
+08:45
+09:00
+09:30
+10:00
+10:30
+11:00
+12:00
+12:45
+13:00
+14:00
```

Please check [here](https://regex101.com/r/lqcgRl/1) for what I have tried so far, and the values I want it to allow.

It works fine for the all the values except for 00:00.
Also, it allows some extra values such as `-19:30` `+23:00` `22:30` `21:00` which should not be allowed.

I want it to allow only those values which have been mentioned in my aforesaid link.

Comment: Well, there's always the brute force way: `-12:00|\+14:00|-11:00|-10:00`… Is this really something that needs to be handled this strictly in a regex?

Comment: Why `-19:30` and `+23:00` are not allowed?

Comment: @HaoWu Presumably because no timezone exists with those offsets, and they're way more than ±12 hours, which makes little sense.

Comment: Note that if you're hardcoding your list of allowed offsets, you're presuming there's a fixed set of offsets and they'll never change. Well… they do occasionally. Being too strict about this is not future-proofing your code very well.

Comment: @deceze Yes it needs to be strict and in a regex. We have a convention of not keeping strings as free text, rather bound their values using regex so that only valid combination of strings are allowed....Do you have any other way to do this?

Comment: @HaoWu - There are no timezones with those offset values!

Comment: Again, the easiest is probably the aforementioned brute force approach. You *could* try to be clever and craft some regex that matches exactly those values *without* listing each one explicitly, but that will take a while to figure out and will be incomprehensible and unmaintainable afterwards.

Comment: @deceze Which is not a problem, since we do not hardcode our regex into the code but have it defined separately like a plug and play. It can be easily modified later. _You could try to be clever and craft some regex that matches exactly those values without listing each one explicitly, but that will take a while to figure out_ Which is something I couldn't do, and that's why I am here seeking for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the results you wanted by slightly tweaking your regex.
This is also short and concise.

```
^(?:(?:[+-](?:1[0-4]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9])|00:00)$
```

You can check the results and test it further [here](https://regex101.com/r/lqcgRl/4)

One point which should be noted here is that you would be able to pass other values between the current valid values of timezone(`-12:00` to `+14:00`). By reading the comments in the question, I feel it is better to have it this way, for future proofing just in case they change. (You would need to tweak the regex to allow values greater than `14:00`)

If you strictly want to limit it to the values which you have listed, enumeration would be a better approach to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

To only match these strings of yours, you can use

```
^(?:\+(?:0(?:[12]:00|[34]:[03]0|5:(?:[03]0|45)|6:[03]0|7:00|8:(?:00|45)|9:[03]0)|1(?:0:[03]0|1:00|2:(?:00|45)|[34]:00))|-(?:0(?:[12]:00|3:[03]0|[4-8]:00|9:[03]0)|1[0-2]:00)|00:00)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5iZuOE/1)

Use online/external tools to build word list regexps like this (e.g. [My Regex Tester](https://myregextester.com/), etc.).

Comment: Thank you, this passes all the values that I was looking for. Is there a way we can shorten this pattern a little bit?